# Django model form saving simultaneously post request twice

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

[image]I am using `django-bootstrap-modal-forms 1.3.1` following `https://pypi.org/project/django-bootstrap-modal-forms/` but if I run it's project of books it calls the post request to create book twice but saves the from once.

As I am using it, it makes twice post request but both the request are saved one with empty file i.e one post saves all the fields of modal like `title` `description`, `date` but not the `upload` (file) and the next post saves all of it with `upload` simultaneously

This is my model :

```
class File(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    visible_to_home = models.ManyToManyField(Home, blank=True)  # when none visible to all home
    visible_to_company = models.ManyToManyField(Company, blank=True)  # when none visible to all company
# To determine visibility, check if vtc is none or include company of user and if true, check same for home
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    published = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    upload = models.FileField(blank=True, null=True, upload_to=update_filename)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=225, blank=True, null=True)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
```

If I remove author then it works fine but as my requirement I need author.

```
class FileForm(PopRequestMixin, CreateUpdateAjaxMixin, forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = File
        fields = ('title', 'description', 'upload')
```

View

```
class FileCreateView(PassRequestMixin, SuccessMessageMixin,
                 CreateView):
    template_name = 'file/upload-file.html'
    form_class = FileForm
    success_message = 'File was uploaded successfully'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('home')

    def post(self, *args, **kwargs):
        """
        Handle POST requests: instantiate a form instance with the passed
        POST variables and then check if it's valid.
        """
        form = self.get_form()
        # form = self.form_class(self.request.POST, self.request.FILES)
        if self.request.method == 'POST':
            if form.is_valid():
                file = form.save(commit=False)
                file.upload = form.cleaned_data['upload']
                file.author = User.objects.get(pk=self.request.user.pk)
                file.save()
                return self.form_valid(form)
            else:
                return self.form_invalid(form)
```

home.html

```
{% block extrascripts %}
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
  $(".upload-file").modalForm({formURL: "{% url 'file-upload' %}"});
 });
</script>
{% endblock extrascripts %}
```

Other is same as the example implementation.

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
 if form.is_valid():
     if not self.request.is_ajax():
         file = form.save(commit=False)
         file.upload = form.cleaned_data['upload']
         file.author = User.objects.get(pk=self.request.user.pk)
         file.save()
```

Comment: This actually worked for me, what was the reason of this issue ?

Answer (score 0):

Adding to alex's answer:
For Django 4 `request.is_ajax():` does not work! `request.headers.get('x-requested-with') == 'XMLHttpRequest':` works for me.

Answer (score -1):

You need to modify your `CreateView`

```
class FileCreateView(PassRequestMixin, SuccessMessageMixin,
                 CreateView):
    template_name = 'file/upload-file.html'
    form_class = FileForm
    success_message = 'File was uploaded successfully'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('home')

    def form_valid(self, form):
       file = form.save(commit=False)
       file.author = self.request.user.pk
       file.save()
       return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('home'))
```

Comment: How do I do that ? Can you please elaborate?

Comment: replace your `FileCreateView` with mine.

Comment: There is no error but the same file is again uploaded twice one with all the description except the `upload` i.e any file and the next uploads all the fields with file

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/186197/discussion-between-shafikur-rahman-and-bishwa-karki).

Comment: Please explain your anwser. I am coming from a slightly different angle and can't understand what you think the problem is in the OP solution and why your rewrite addresses the issue. As a result, this answer is unusable.