# Nonetype object has no attribute is_ajax

Tags: ajax, django, django-forms, django-rest-framework, django-views

I am using [Django-bootstrap-modal-forms](https://pypi.org/project/django-bootstrap-modal-forms/) in my project. But I want little customization and have added `Upload` and `Author` field as foreign key. If I do as of the library it works fine. But here I am getting `Nonetype object has no attribute is_ajax`. I don't know why it is `Nonetype` even though I am logged in.

Model :

```
class File(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    visible_to_home = models.ManyToManyField(Home, blank=True)  # when none visible to all home
    visible_to_company = models.ManyToManyField(Company, blank=True)  
# when none visible to all company
# To determine visibility, check if vtc is none or include company of user and if true, check same for home
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    published = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    upload = models.FileField(blank=True, null=True, upload_to=update_filename)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=225, blank=True, null=True)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
```

Forms

```
class FileForm(PopRequestMixin, CreateUpdateAjaxMixin, forms.ModelForm):
class Meta:
    model = File
    fields = ('title', 'description', 'upload')
```

View

```
class FileCreateView(PassRequestMixin, SuccessMessageMixin,
             CreateView):
    template_name = 'file/upload-file.html'
    form_class = FileForm
    success_message = 'File was uploaded successfully'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('home')

def post(self, *args, **kwargs):
    """
    Handle POST requests: instantiate a form instance with the passed
    POST variables and then check if it's valid.
    """
    #form = self.get_form()
    form = self.form_class(self.request.POST, self.request.FILES)
    if self.request.method == 'POST':
        if form.is_valid():
            file = form.save(commit=False)
            file.upload = form.cleaned_data['upload']
            file.author = User.objects.get(pk=self.request.user.pk)
            file.save()
            return self.form_valid(form)
        else:
            return self.form_invalid(form)
```

Here in the post method of view if I use `form = self.get_form()` instead of `form = self.form_class(self.request.POST, self.request.FILES)` then the [Django model form saving simultaneously post request twice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54041660/django-model-form-saving-simultaneously-post-request-twice/54042002?noredirect=1#comment94920067_54042002) problem occurs.

home.html

```
{% block extrascripts %}
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function () {
     $(".upload-file").modalForm({formURL: "{% url 'file-upload' %}"});
  });
 </script>
{% endblock extrascripts %}
```

Trace back :

```
File "/home/bishwa/PycharmProjects/sharefile/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 35, in inner
response = get_response(request)
File "/home/bishwa/PycharmProjects/sharefile/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 128, in _get_response
response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
File "/home/bishwa/PycharmProjects/sharefile/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 126, in _get_response
response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "/usr/lib/python3.6/contextlib.py", line 52, in inner
return func(*args, **kwds)
File "/home/bishwa/PycharmProjects/sharefile/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py", line 69, in view
return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/home/bishwa/PycharmProjects/sharefile/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py", line 89, in dispatch
return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/home/bishwa/PycharmProjects/sharefile/sharefile/file/views.py", line 103, in post
file = form.save(commit=False)
File "/home/bishwa/PycharmProjects/sharefile/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/bootstrap_modal_forms/mixins.py", line 40, in save
if not self.request.is_ajax():
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'is_ajax'
```

[06/Jan/2019 00:06:30] "POST /upload/file/ HTTP/1.1" 500 110437

As per the library I am using, it says `On submit the form is POSTed via AJAX request to formURL`
I think I traced the error i.e. I need to make a ajax request when `file = form.save(commit=False)` and `file.save()` method is called in `post` function. Do you have any idea how can I do that ?

Answer: so finally I solved it :

```
class FileForm(PopRequestMixin, CreateUpdateAjaxMixin, forms.ModelForm):
class Meta:
    model = File
    fields = ('title', 'description', 'upload')

def save(self, commit=False):

    if not self.request.is_ajax():
        instance = super(CreateUpdateAjaxMixin, self).save(commit=commit)
        instance.author = User.objects.get(pk=self.request.user.pk)
        instance.save()
    else:
        instance = super(CreateUpdateAjaxMixin, self).save(commit=False)

    return instance
```

The `save` method is overridden from `CreateUpdateAjaxMixin` and I removed the `post` method in the view.

Comment: This doesn't look like an AJAX request. Where is your AJAX code?

Comment: Actually I am following [https://pypi.org/project/django-bootstrap-modal-forms/] [1]

Comment: Oh, my bad. You should add your trace back, and probably want to fix your indentations in your posted code.

Comment: Now I have added trave back and in the library that I am using it says it submits post vai ajax to formURL

Comment: I'm not familiar with the package, but my guess is that `def post` should actually be a `method` under your `class View` and not a standalone `definition`. [ like here ](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/class-based-views/intro/#handling-forms-with-class-based-views). More than that, I don't know. You probably want to update your form indentation as well.

Comment: @CarlBrubaker thank you so much for your help. I solved it .

Comment: What was the solution?

Comment: @CarlBrubaker no but I had overridden the `CreateUpdateAjaxMixin`'s `save` method in the form.py . You can see the final edit